# Use JSON to extract parameters from URL

Tags: json

How do extract parameters from the URL when the method is posted using JSON?

Comment: JSON has nothing to do with URLs. One does not "post a method using JSON" either. Do you mean JavaScript?

Comment: I'm guessing that what he means is that the post body is JSON. Just a guess.

Comment: i am trying to extract the parameter that pass from one webpage to another and output the paramater in JSON format and the method used is POST instead of GET so i am not sure how to extract the parameter.

Comment: Question still doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 8):

I guess that you are getting the response in JSON form

for extracting the parameters you can use Newtonsoft.Json.dll.You will get the documentation here :- http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx or after getting the data you can use usual crawling methods for extracting the data