# How do I use JSONRequest.POST to get parameters from a url?

Tags: json, url, post, parameters, request

how to get POST parameters at a URL, using JSONRequest. The original site will be www.abc.com/aServlet. For example, www.abc.com/aServlet?user=tom I want to get the paramter of"user" which is "tom". I am actually keying in the user manually in aServlet which is a servlet.

The problem is I dont know how to use JSONRequest to retrieve the parameters. Please help.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883035/use-json-to-extract-parameters-from-url please rephrase the original question to make it understandable rather than opening a new. It still doesn't make sense however.

Answer (score 1):

i think that what he is trying to do is to get the parameter "user" from the URL. I suppose request.getParameter cannot be used since it is a POST method. So, I think he is trying to get the "user" parameter that is passed to the servlet (aServlet) via POST.